# Unable to extract temperature values based on lat, lon from STAC CMIP6 data

Tags: python, coordinate-system, climate, stac

I am using Microsoft Planetary Computer in Google Colab to extract *Tasmax* data from a CMIP6 ACCESS-CM2 model. I have the coordinates of multiple cities across the world and I am trying to get the temperature value at the respective coordinates.

Following is the code snippet:

```
# Get the nc file
search = catalog.search(
    collections=["nasa-nex-gddp-cmip6"],
    datetime='2000',
    query={"cmip6:model": {"eq": "ACCESS-CM2"}},
)
items = search.item_collection()
item = items[0]

ncfile = xr.open_dataset(fsspec.open(item.assets["tasmax"].href).open(), decode_coords="all")

# Get the average tasmax for year 2000
mean = ncfile.tasmax.mean(dim='time')

# Create a new column named 'temp_2000' in the df
df['temp_2000'] = None

# Populate 'temp_2000' column with corresponding temperature values
temp_values_list = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    lat, lon = row['Latitude'], row['Longitude']
    temp_value = mean.sel(lat=lat, lon=lon, method='nearest').item()
    temp_values_list.append(temp_value)

# Put the list as the row values of the 'temp_2000' column
df['temp_2000'] = temp_values_list
```

When I plot the **mean** xarray dataset, following is the image obtained:

[image]

Every city in my list of cities should have an associated tasmax value, but for cities in Argentina the values show up to be NaN.

I tried modifying the code as follows:

```
lat, lon = row['Latitude'], row['Longitude'] - 180 if row['Longitude'] >= 180 else row['Longitude']
```

But now cities in Brazil show NaN values.

Where might I have gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution.

The modified code should have been:

```
lat, lon = row['Latitude'], row['Longitude'] +360 if row['Longitude'] < 0 else row['Longitude']
```

I had an oversight, and was converting the nc data coordinates to match the csv file coordinates.